# Cancel alarm and test if pending intent exist

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to cancel alarm when this alarm exist

```
fun isAlarmWorking(context: Context): Boolean {
    val intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context.applicationContext,
        ALARM_ID,
        createAlarmReceiver(context.applicationContext),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
    return intent != null
}

fun cancelAlarm(context: Context) {
    val intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context.applicationContext,
        ALARM_ID,
        createAlarmReceiver(context.applicationContext),
        0)
    val alarmManager = 
        context.applicationContext.systemService<AlarmManager>()
    alarmManager.cancel(intent)
}
```

so it's look good

1. i test if `PendingIntent` exist with `FLAG_NO_CREATE`
2. cancel alarm with same `ALARM_ID`

but when i test it on real device

```
Timber.d("onClick: ${isAlarmWorking(this)}")
cancelAlarm(this)
Timber.d("onCancel: ${isAlarmWorking(this)}")
```

i get

```
onClick: false
onCancel: true
```

why after call `cancel` i get `true`?

[EDIT] after i add

```
intent.cancel()
```

at the end of `cancelAlarm` result of the test start looking good

```
onClick: false
onCancel: false
```

so i understand that `isAlarmWorking` ask if there any `PendingIntent` in system but not alarm itself, am i right?

Comment: Did you find solve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The code in `isAlarmWorking` just checks if there exists a `PendingIntent` matching the `PendingIntent` that you specify. It does not check if there is an alarm set with that `PendingIntent`.